# How to send array by post method

Tags: php

Following is my sample form.

```
<form METHOD="post" METHOD="post" ACTION="index.php" METHOD="post" METHOD="post" METHOD="post">
<input TYPE="text" NAME="array[]" />
<input TYPE="text" NAME="array[]" />
<input TYPE="text" NAME="array[]" />
<input TYPE="text" NAME="array[]" />
<input TYPE="text" NAME="array[]" />
<input TYPE="text" NAME="array[]" />
<input TYPE="text" NAME="array[]" />
<input TYPE="text" NAME="array[]" />
<input TYPE="text" NAME="array[]" />
<input TYPE="text" NAME="array[]" />
<input TYPE="submit" NAME="submit" VALUE="Submit" />
</form>
```

Basically I have 10 inputs of array. Assume my domain is http://domain.com and the file above is index.php. I am trying to fill the form automatically by using the following method.

http://domain.com/index.php?array[]=John&array[]=Kelly ... & array[]=Steven

Unfortunately, it is not working. :(

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this:

```
<?php
  foreach( $_GET['array'] as $arr )                                    // Loop through the `array` variables of GET
     echo '<input type="text" name="array[]" value="' . $arr . '" />'; // Display the the inputs
?>
```

However, please make sure that you use a cleaning function on $arr to prevent XSS. You will also need to check if $_GET['array'] is set or not, or PHP will whine about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to fill the form from a GET request (your URL string), you have to get the values from the HTTP request in the $_REQUEST array (or $_GET or $_POST depending on the form method).  Suggestion: you should change the names of the form fields to reflect the value they are storing

```
<form METHOD="post" METHOD="post" ACTION="index.php" METHOD="post" METHOD="post" METHOD="post">
<input TYPE="text" NAME="first_name" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['first_name']?>"/>
```

Note: accessing the $_REQUEST array as shown above is not good practice as you need to check if the request variables are set before you can echo their values.

```
<form METHOD="post" METHOD="post" ACTION="index.php" METHOD="post" METHOD="post" METHOD="post">
<input TYPE="text" NAME="first_name" value="<?php echo isset($_REQUEST['first_name'])?$_REQUEST['first_name']:""?>"/>
```

Comment: I wish I could change the form to GET, unfortunate the form is belong to other party. I am trying to build a script to submit the data to the party by using curl. They are using array[] as their input, the name of the input of course. Any idea how to auto submit data?

Answer (score 0):

Two things to try.

1. You are using the GET method with your example URL, but your form is set to POST. In your PHP, you may be looking for your data in $_POST when it's actually in $_GET. You can get data from both POST and GET using the $_REQUEST variable.
2. You may need to urlencode the []. ([] becomes %5B%5D when urlencoded.)

Lastly, a tip: when crafting links to send data through a GET query string, it is best practice to use `&amp;` in place of the &'s in the URL.